# Digest subscription links -- page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, newsletter, 404-not-found

When I click on any of the subscription links on the [Digest](https://stackexchange.com/digests) page, I get slapped by a panda.

Should that even lead to a "page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that. Apparently I renamed routes in the views but not on the backend. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

The fix is out in production now.